# Erro: That is not equal to the supplied origin

Tags: angular, heroku

Estou uma tentando buscar registros que estão numa API no servidor **heroku** com a seguinte URL `https://mdw-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com/noticias`

Porém quando vou receber essa url no meu projeto Angular ele gera esse erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é minha classe de serviços do Angular

```
import { Noticia } from './../core/model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import * as moment from 'moment';

export class NoticiaFiltro {
  titulo: string;
  font: string;
  pagina = 0;
 itensPorPagina = 8;

}


@Injectable()
export class NoticiaService {


 noticiasUrl = 'https://mdw-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com/noticias';


  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  pesquisar(filtro: NoticiaFiltro): Promise<any> {

    const params = new URLSearchParams();

    const headers = new Headers();

    params.set('page', filtro.pagina.toString());
    params.set('size', filtro.itensPorPagina.toString());

    if (filtro.titulo) {
      params.set('titulo', filtro.titulo);
    }

    if (filtro.font) {
      params.set('font', filtro.font);
    }

    return this.http.get(`${this.noticiasUrl}`, { headers, search: params  })
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        const responseJson = response.json();
        const noticias = responseJson.content;

        const resultado = {
          noticias,
          total: responseJson.totalElements
        };

        return resultado;
    });
  }


     adicionar(noticia: Noticia): Promise<Noticia> {
            const headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            return this.http.post(this.noticiasUrl,
                JSON.stringify(noticia), { headers })
              .toPromise()
              .then(response => response.json());
        }

        excluir(codigo: number): Promise<void> {
          const headers = new Headers();

          return this.http.delete(`${this.noticiasUrl}/${codigo}`, { headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(() => null);
      }


      atualizar(noticia: Noticia): Promise<Noticia> {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return this.http.put(`${this.noticiasUrl}/${noticia.codigo}`,
            JSON.stringify(noticia), { headers })
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => {
            const lancamentoAlterado = response.json() as Noticia;

            this.converterStringsParaDatas([lancamentoAlterado]);

            return lancamentoAlterado;
          });
      }



      buscarPorCodigo(codigo: number): Promise<Noticia> {
        const headers = new Headers();

        return this.http.get(`${this.noticiasUrl}/${codigo}`, { headers })
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => {
            const noticia = response.json() as Noticia;

            this.converterStringsParaDatas([noticia]);

            return noticia;
          });
    }


        private converterStringsParaDatas(noticias: Noticia[]) {
          for (const noticia of noticias) {
            noticia.dataNoticia = moment(noticia.dataNoticia,
              'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate();
              }
            }



}
```

**Alguém saberia como me ajudar a resolver esse problema?**

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o erro, o domínio que está a fazer a requisição não tem permissão para isso.

> localhost:4200

O browser valida essa informação através do cabeçalho `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` enviado na resposta da requisição. Você pode utilizar a console (aba Network) do Chrome para verificar os cabeçalhos enviados pelo servidor Heroku.

Utilizando o Postman, é possível ver que o domínio autorizado é `http://localhost:8000`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como a origem da requisição `localhost:4200` é diferente da origem permitida `localhost:8000` pelo servidor Heroku, o browser bloqueia o GET Request.

Por padrão, o angular inicia um servidor na porta 4200. Para resolver o problema, mude a porta no momento em que iniciar o serve:

```
ng serve --port 8000
```

Comment: tanto a minha API Java como a API Angular está no servidor Heroku e minha API Angular está dando o mesmo problema será necessário eu setar uma porta para minha API angular?